# Getting a specific item from a list in BsonDocument

Tags: c#, mongodb, bson

I am trying to get an item from a list with `Where()` in a BsonDocument to form a query. Participants is a `List<User>` where I would like to get a specific participant from. `Components` is a `List<BsonDocument>`, this makes indexing with `["key"]` possible, because the properties on the object aren't known yet.

```js
var rec = (await _context.Records
                        .Where(r =>
                        r.Components.Any(c =>
                        c["StartTime"] == record.StartTime &&
                        c["Participants.Number"] == record.Organizer.Number))
                        .GetAsync())
                        .LastOrDefault();
```

`["Participants.Number"]` works on the list, but I would like to only check on a specific (second) participant in the list, I tried the following:

`p["Participants[1].Number"]`

`p["Participants"][1]["Number"]`

I also tried first converting to `BsonArray` and other `LINQ` functionality but didn't succeed in finding a solution.

Comment: Which BsonDocument framework are you using? Mongo?

Comment: Yes I am using the MongoDB driver and `MongoDB.Bson`

Comment: have you tried "Participants.1.Number" as that is the way mongo would reference it internally

Comment: I have not, I will try it out and let you know

Comment: I believe it works! Thank you for helping out, do you know what I should do if I wanted the last item from the list (list could have variable length)

Comment: you would probably have to compose a pipeline query that calls "$reverseArray" see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the Query isn't running in your code its being passed to the underlying database and unlike c#, mongo doesn't use square bracket notation for array indexing it uses the same indexing as object notation so you need `.1` instead of `[1]`

Comment: Does that mean I can do all the Mongo like indexing in brackets?

Comment: if you return the data from mongo and query in c# yes, but you are much better off letting mongo handle the querying so you need to work to the mongo standard

Comment: What do you mean by let mongo handle the querying? Thank you btw

Comment: currently you are composing a query in the bsonDocument that is being passed to mongo to run, hence why you needed to use the mongo indexing syntax, the other alternative would be to use a more minimal query that returns a greater number of records to your code and then you can provide additional filtering of the results in code, using "LINQ to Objects" while this would work it would be vastly more inefficient than letting mongo filter out the records you don't want